# How to multiply a given row `i` or column `j` with a scalar?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

M = np.matrix([
        [-1,-2,-3],
        [-4,-5,-6]
    ])

print(M)
```

1. How to multiply a given row `i` or column `j` with a scalar?
2. How to acces a given column or row as a list?
3. How to set a given column or row, given a list (of the appropiate length)?

Comment: how about starting with the numpy tutorial, http://www.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial Or this guide for people coming from matlab, http://www.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users It includes a discussion of when numpy.matrix might be more appropriate than the more standard numpy.array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing) to accomplish this:

```
>>> M = np.matrix([
...         [-1,-2,-3],
...         [-4,-5,-6]
...     ])
>>> M[1,:] *= 2          # multiply all elements in second row by 2
>>> M
matrix([[ -1,  -2,  -3],
        [ -8, -10, -12]])
>>> M[:,1] *= 2          # multiply all elements in second column by 2
>>> M
matrix([[ -1,  -4,  -3],
        [ -8, -20, -12]])
```

To assign a given column or row to a list:

```
>>> M[:,1] = [[0], [0]]        # note the nested lists to reassign column
>>> M
matrix([[ -1,   0,  -3],
        [ -8,   0, -12]])
>>> M[1,:] = [2, 2, 2]         # flat list to reassign row
>>> M
matrix([[-1,  0, -3],
        [ 2,  2,  2]])
```

Comment: good link, but notice you're not using any advanced indexing here only basic slicing. The difference between the two and why it matters is described in the link.

Answer (score 7):

To multiply a particular column:

```
M[:,colnumber] *= scalar
```

Or a row:

```
M[rownumber,:] *= scalar
```

And of course, accessing them as an iterable is the same thing:

```
col_1 = M[:,1]
```

Although, that gives you a new matrix, not a `list`.  Although, honestly, I can't quite seem to figure out all of these operations with `matrix` objects -- And these don't really seem like `matrix` type operations.  Is there a reason that you're using `matrix` instead of `array` objects?  If you want matrix multiplication, you can always use `np.dot(array_mat1, array_mat2)`

Comment: And, of course, if you _had_ to have a `list` you could always get that with `list(col_1)`, but that temptation is worth fighting in most (all?) cases.

Comment: Setting can be done the same way. For instance, `M[:,1] = [0,0]` will replace the second column with `0`s.

Comment: @MattTenenbaum -- I'm actually working that one out.  It seems that doesn't quite work with the columns.

Comment: Ah, yes. It works on ndarray, but not with `numpy.matrix`. Convert to array, then back?

Comment: @MattTenenbaum -- *shrugs* I say pick an appropriate data-type to begin with.  99% of the time that's `np.ndarray`.  You can still do matrix multiplication with `np.dot`.

Comment: matrices always keep a two-dimensional shape, so `M[:,1]` has shape `(2, 1)`, not `(2,)`. `M[:, 1] = [[0], [0]]` should work.

Comment: @mgilson I agree completely.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Python 2.7**

1) You can multiply a row or a column by some scalar `s` like this:

```
M[i, :] *= s
M[:, j] *= s
```

2) You can access a row or column like this:

```
M[i, :]
M[:, j]
```

3) You can set a row or column to a list `l` like this:

```
M[i, :] = l
M[:, j] = l
```

Note that in the last one, your list (if you are setting a column) would have to be a list within a list (i.e. the outer list acts as a row, the inner lists act as columns).

Comment: I'm not sure about the second one in 3).  When experimenting, I get:  `M[:,1] = 2,3` -- `ValueError: output operand requires a reduction, but reduction is not enabled`

Comment: The second one worked for me, he asked about setting a "a list (of the appropiate length)" to a column or row. Therefore, you would use M[:,1] = [[2],[3]]

Comment: Thanks for the notes though, I updated my answer to reflect this.